# Surely there's a way to simulate a click on a HasClickHandlers object in GWT

Tags: gwt

When I use Buttons, I can just call button.click() to simulate a click.  Now I have a reference to a HasClickHandlers (might be a button, might be an image, etc), but can't figure out how to click it!

Is it possible?  I'm using GWT 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following and populate the fields as needed such as screen position and such.

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createClickEvent(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false), button);
```

Comment: What is `button`?  All I have is a reference to a `HasClickHandlers` object.

Comment: Button is an instance of a GWT button object which implements HasClickHandlers, but I believe the method requires HasHandlers.

Comment: @Riley If you look at the doc for DomEvent.fireNativeEvent() http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html you will see, that it takes a HasHandlers object. HasClickHandlers is a subinterface of HasHandlers so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you invoke `fireEvent()` from the superinterface `HasHandlers`?

Also, take a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/35c4f34010b146f5?pli=1).

Comment: The answer in that post relies on having an element to fire from, but all I have is a HasClickHandlers reference.  I could assume that it's also a Widget object and cast it to get an Element, I suppose...